# IE8 not able to calculate Math.ceil()

Tags: javascript, math, internet-explorer-8

I have the following code and have tried everything to parse all the numbers so that IE doesn't throw a fit:

```
var firt_payment = 0.0;
var subscription = 0.0;
var no_policies = 0;
var policy_cost = 100.0;
if (typeof interval == "undefined") {
    var interval = 0;
}
var days_left = daysLeftMonth(interval);
var days_month = daysInMonth();

$("input[name^='policies']:checkbox").change(function() {
    var el = $(this);

    if (el.is(":checked")) {
        no_policies++;
    }

    if (el.is(":not(:checked)")) {
        no_policies--;
    }

    subscription = Number(no_policies*policy_cost);

    var interim_val = 0.0;
    if (no_policies > 0) {
        interim_val = no_policies*(policy_cost/days_month)*days_left;
    }

    first_payment = Math.ceil(subscription+interim_val).toFixed(2);

    $("td#first_payment").text("R "+first_payment);
    $("input#first_payment_txt").val(first_payment);
    $("td#subscription").text("R "+subscription.toFixed(2));    
});
```

Does anyone have an answer for me as to why

```
first_payment = Math.ceil(subscription+interim_val).toFixed(2);
```

does not get calculated on IE8?

Please, I'm desperate over here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the resulting output? What is expected? What other browsers does it work in?

Comment: On Safari, the output is R126.00 works every time, only IE8 can't comprehend that all the inputs are numbers. `first_payment = subscription+interim_val;` also gives an error on IE8. The error I get is: `Object doesn't support this property or method`

Comment: Well what are the values of `subscription` and `interim_val`? Perhaps they're not both numbers (or are strings containing numbers)?

Comment: Apologies, `alert(subscription+interim_val);` alerts `125.806...` but the `Math.ceil()` function refuses to calculate.

Comment: What is amazing is that this question has been viewed 86 times, yet nobody saw the spelling mistake in the first line that lead to the whole mess. Apologies for the wasted time, but it was very late at night, and I had been staring at the piece of code for about 2 hours straight. Voting to close now.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't use `Number` to cast as numeric, you should instead use `parseInt` or `parseFloat` and then check the result with `isNaN`.  In addition, you are not verifying the output of `daysLeftMonth` or `daysInMonth`, and the `days_left` value may contain a `NaN` value which would pollute the `subscription+interim_val` operation taking place inside the Math.ceil.

Comment: Why does this work flawlessly on Safari but not IE8? Would `alert(isNan(whateverVariable));` point me to the value which is causing the problem?

Comment: Zikes, I really need your input on this, I would be eternally grateful.

Comment: @Anriëtte Combrink It's difficult to pinpoint the exact cause on my end, but the easiest way to spot the culprit is lots of `alert()`s and `typeof`s.  It's looking like one of the values is non-numeric, and could need casted with `parseFloat`.

Comment: I tried that, nothing worked, eventually I just put `var` in front of `first_payment = Math.ceil(subscription+interim_val).toFixed(2);` and NOW it's working. I can't believe I wasted all that time.